# How to display time in required format?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display time in HH:MM AM/PM format.
date format :

```js
new Date(2015, 4, 21, 19, 30, 0),
```

function to convert date in HH:MM format:

```js
  function conertTime(time){
    var localeSpecificTime = time.toLocaleTimeString();
    return localeSpecificTime.replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');
}
```

Comment: You mean, "hh:mm A" format? The case of the "H" matters.

Comment: Yeah, in hh:mm and with am/pm as well

Comment: You can use e.g. https://date-fns.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the time using [`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString). The documentation includes examples of options you can pass-in.

If `hour12` is `false`, the time will be rendered in 24-hour time and the meridiem will not be included.

```js
const
  date = new Date(2015, 4, 21, 19, 30, 0),
  formatted = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
  });

console.log(formatted);
```